# Why do 'The Wiggles' appear to wear Starfleet uniforms?

Tags: star-trek

As in the question header, I recently had to sit through 2 hours of The Wiggles (with my grandson) and I noticed they are wearing what appears to be [Starfleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfleet) uniforms.

Is there a reason for this? Was there a Star Trek link to Australia at some time?

[image]

Comment: They are Trekkies???

Comment: It's sad that you've had to pretend that your grandson was there. Just admit that you jig along with The Wiggles!

Comment: Ha! You got me dead to rights, I am a secret Wiggler

Comment: You've only posted this question because the Yellow Wiggle is doing the Vulcan salute!

Comment: The sad thing is I looked at that photo and, even though it's mainly the original line-up, I managed to name three of them.

Comment: What part of the ship does the purple-shirted guy work in?

Comment: @EvilSnack - it's a specialized off shoot of medical, sleep technicians. Constantly trying to improve the quality of the crews sleep, often by testing new techniques on themselves, which then required other crew members to wake them up.

Comment: Did the redshirt Wiggle last longer than a single episode?

Comment: @LincolnMan : Actually, in keeping with the redshirt mythos, he's been replaced a couple of times since the Wiggles began!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This was addressed in [an interview](https://www.timeoutabudhabi.com/kids/features/23778-the-wiggles-in-abu-dhabi) with Red Wiggle Murray Cook. In short, the colour selection was nothing to do with Star Trek. They just picked bold colours that kids would recognise and remember.

> **Q.** *Looking at your uniforms, they look a bit Star Trek-esque. Were you thinking of Spock and Kirk when you designed them?*
>
> **A. *No, not at all. Our uniforms were just a good way for the kids to identify which Wiggle was which by association with colours.***

So, a case of convergent evolution, not emulation.

Comment: They aren't all usual Star Trek colors anyway, at least not from TOS. Lachy's uniform is purple.

Comment: @Tronman - It all depends on the lighting; https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0e7Y.jpg

Comment: Actually, they are *The Orville* Planetary Union uniforms.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Star Trek also chose uniforms with bold, distinct colors so even on early color televisions in the 1960's you could tell what color everyone was wearing.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian - You are correct, Sir.  http://www.startrekpropauthority.com/2008/05/bill-theiss-lost-interview-rare.html - *"A film stock thing*"